# How to save KSOP2 response to xml in android SD card?

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

In my project I am calling a web-service which giving response back as thousands of records from SQL server but as default size of SOAP ENVELOPE is 64KB I am getting only first 15 records in my log-cat and `OutOfMemory` exception...
Please tell me how to write this response in xml file in SD card.

```
private static String SOAP_ACTION1 ="http://tempuri.org/DownloadAllMasterDataRelatedToFarmer";
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static String METHOD_NAME1 = "DownloadAllMasterDataRelatedToFarmer";
private static String URL = "http://someIP/Tracebaledemo/fieldbook/webservice1.asmxwsdl";

(...)

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);
request.addProperty("prefixText",txtFar.getText().toString());
request.addProperty("count",txtCount.getText().toString());
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
envelope.dotNet = true;

try {
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    Log.d(TAG, "Entering Try and calling WebService");

    //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);

    // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
    Log.d(TAG, "Fetching Results");

    SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
    Log.d(TAG, "Result from WebService before if block= "+result);
} (...)
```

Answer (score -1):

You Saving Your xml just to fetch your `records` if it is not necessary You can do

Why Dont you define a limit to your `Activity`

```
Suppose 30 records per hit
```

or You can also refine your webService  And You can use a `Footer` showing `Loading more`
in this Way you can see your records

DrawBack- It Will take time to fetch your records as you said u have 10,000 records

Solution- You can refine your webservice By Using 1st Letter of your Search Event 
I hope u Getting what i am trying to say 
If no, Please let me know

Comment: First Thanks for your reply.I am getting response as an XML having about 10,000 records and as I can't use it directly, I have to first save it android sd card and then I can use it by parsing as required.When I am trying to print whole SOAP RESPONSE I am getting out of memory exception....How to get InputStream of SOAP RESOPNSE