# How to save webservice SOAP response to xml in android SD card?

Tags: android, soap, download, sd-card

I have a SOAP webservice from an application aspnet, and do not know how to generate a file on the sdcard of my device for future reading.

What are the steps?

I read the webservice with ksop2? 
Generate an xml file of response the SOAP service?
I record this xml file generated in the sdcard?

I read this [How to save KSOP2 response to xml in android SD card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913001/how-to-save-ksop2-response-to-xml-in-android-sd-card)

But i don't understand, because the code is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

What do you do with the SOAP response? If you're creating objects from it I would save them with db4o instead of the SOAP Xml. You got your stuff already parsed then and using db4o is very pleasant :)

Comment: The file recorded by the SOAP response is to use the Android application when no internet connection.


What is the best format for reading on Android, XML, JSON, ...?

Comment: I would definitely prefer JSON with the Gson library provided by Google. Imho SOAP is the ugliest format to handle in Java.

Comment: The web application is SOAP service in aspnet plataform, and i dont have acess.

Can i generate a Json from SOAP webservice with a Gson library?

Comment: I don't think that's feasable. I have to work with SOAP too at the moment, I parse the stuff "by hand" with ksoap2.